# What error am I making when trying to pass data between ViewControllers using closures?

Tags: ios, swift

My main View Controller has an embedded UITabbarController in it. There are 2 subVCs: viewControllerONE & viewControllerTWO.

viewControllerONE displays a label showing the user's current score, and viewControllerTWO displays a button, pressing which should display an error window on viewControllerONE.
 (For the sake of simplicity, the user has to manually navigate to viewControllerONE using the tab bar to see the error, ie, pressing the button on viewControllerTWO doesn't take you to viewControllerONE and then display the errorWindow.)

The error window is a simple UIView class.

From SO, I have learnt that the best way to pass data in swift isn't delegates but closures, as the former is more of an objective C design, and so I've used closures to pass data between view controllers.

So here is my viewControllerONE code:

```
class ViewControllerONE: UIViewController {

    var score = 10

    lazy var scoreLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = String(score)
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 80)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(scoreLabel)

         let VC = ViewControllerTWO()

    VC.callback = { [weak self ] in
        let error = errorView()
        self?.view.addSubview(error)
        }


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scoreLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        scoreLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
    ])

  }
```

}

and here is my viewControllerTWO code:

```
class ViewControllerTWO: UIViewController {

    var callback: (() -> Void)?

    let buttonTwo: UIButton = {
             let button = UIButton()
             button.setTitle("HIT THIS BUTTON!", for: .normal)
             button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
             button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
             button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTwoPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
             button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
             return button
         }()

         @objc func buttonTwoPressed() {
             print("PRESSEDDDD")
            callback?()
         }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(buttonTwo)

                 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                 buttonTwo.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                 buttonTwo.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }

}
```

And here is the error view:

```
class ErrorView: UIView {


    fileprivate let dismissButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("DISMISS!!!!", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return button
    }()

    @objc func dismissButtonPressed() {
    self.errorGoAway()
    }


    fileprivate let errorViewBox: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 24
        return v
    }()

    @objc fileprivate func errorGoAway() {
            self.alpha = 0
    }

    @objc fileprivate func errorShow() {
        self.alpha = 1
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(errorGoAway)))
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        self.backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        self.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        self.addSubview(errorViewBox)

        errorViewBox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        errorViewBox.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        errorViewBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.7).isActive = true
        errorViewBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.45).isActive = true

        errorViewBox.addSubview(dismissButton)
        dismissButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: errorViewBox.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        dismissButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: errorViewBox.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        dismissButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: errorViewBox.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        dismissButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: errorViewBox.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.15).isActive = true

        errorShow()
    }
```

Comment: `viewControllerTWO()` creates a new instance of the controller which is thrown away at the end of `viewDidLoad`. By the way please name classes with starting uppercase letter.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `ViewController2` and setting the closure on that. That instance is then thrown away since it is a local variable. You need to assign the closure on the instance that is actually managed by your tab bar controller. Your tab bar controller will have the required object references.

Comment: Would you know of any documentation I can reference for this, I tend to make this error a lot and am still blank on how to rectify this.

Comment: @vadian can you check if I have rectified the mistake by changing my code in ViewDidLoad() of ViewControllerOne() ?  Although this still does not solve my OG Question
(I don't know if asking for clarifications in comments is allowed or not so let me know if I should delete this)

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59434698/edit) the question to add information. Your updated code doesn't make any difference because it's still a local variable. Nevertheless if the controller is designed in a storyboard the instance is not even the instance in the storyboard.

Comment: No, all controllers have been designed programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your controller from tabBarController instead of create new instance:

```
class ViewControllerONE: UIViewController {

var score = 10

lazy var scoreLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = String(score)
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 80)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .blue
    return label
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    view.addSubview(scoreLabel)

    var VC: ViewControllerTWO?

    let arrayOfVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers ?? []

    for item in arrayOfVC {
        if let secondVC = item as? ViewControllerTWO {
            VC = secondVC
            break
        }
    }

    VC?.callback = { [weak self ] in
        let error = ErrorView()
        self?.view.addSubview(error)
    }

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scoreLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        scoreLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
    ])

  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, but unfortunately this did not solve my issue

Comment: @swiftnjava check this project https://github.com/Tuichev/TestApp